# Short animation in React project

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I was just searching online and found a nice animation in this website. 
https://marketplace.walmart.com/

The homepage has a animation which they display like a slideshow. A new frame shows up after every 2 seconds or so and it is interactive. MEans if you click anything on that animation, it will create an event and perform actions.

I want this similar feature in my application. So i searched online for animations in React App. I found Velocity.js and Parallax as the  animation. Mostly in these, animations are shown when we are scrolling the page. My requirement is similar to the one mentioned in the link.

Any inputs/ suggestions for how to get the slideshow kind of animation. I am very naive at this and need suggestions. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Events can be fired in multiple fashions in React. There are a lot of resources out there to get you started on the different types, but I recommend the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). If you need a good starting point. I suggest implementing the arrows on the page first to use and onclick event to slide html/React components along the page. You can the combine this with a timed events to trigger the other actions. In regards to the animations themselves, there are plenty of resources out there. Here's one to maybe get you started: [CSS Transitions](https://speckyboy.com/page-transition-effects/)